# Firefox blocking our site due to SSLv3

Tags: security, firefox, ssl

Several users have emailed us to report that they cannot access our site using Firefox because we're using SSLv3. The problem is, we discontinued support for SSLv3 a while ago. I've tested our site using the Qualys SSL Labs scanner and the report says we don't support SSLv3. I've also tried initiating a handshake from the command line using SSLv3 and it returns the correct error.

Has anybody dealt with this? Could anybody guess what's going on here? It's driving me nuts. I've tried restarting our servers, changing what ciphers we support (not protocols-- we only support TLSv1), promoting new servers to master via keepalived, and more. Users continue to complain that Firefox won't let them access our site.

Comment: I think this is rather a question for http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post there